# Is Laravel-Mix important for me to be able to use ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-mix

I have a Laravel 7 project that I will have to integrate ReactJS into.

In fact, in order for my project to display correctly, I have to disable laravel-mix, otherwise the CSS is not loaded (as the console shows you).

[image]

In order to work around this issue, I had to disable laravel-mix (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/overlap_github/myproject/webpack.mix.js) by setting it to false like this:

```
'enabled_laravel_mix' => false,
```

My question :

Is Laravel-Mix important for me to be able to use ReactJS?

Because I will have to integrate a ReactJS component.

Comment: I've been using mix with react for a while at work and the CSS files were loading ok for me. How are you using that CSS? Is it copied correctly to the public directory?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Now, all is working great.  I wish you the best.